# Phonon wavevector $q\le 2k_{F}$ for Electron-Phonon Scattering

Tags: condensed-matter

I am reading "Supercollision cooling in undoped graphene." [There](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v9/n2/full/nphys2494.html) the authors write: ``Above $T_{BG}$ (the Bloch-Gruneisen temperature), only a fraction of acoustic phonons with wave vector $q\le 2k_{F}$ can scatter off electrons."

I assume the condition $q\le 2k_{F}$ for electron-phonon scattering is a basic result, but I couldn't find it proved anywhere. Could anyone point me in the right direction, or state the proof here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electron-phonon scattering is a process that takes the electron across its Fermi surface (from an occupied state to an empty state, or vice versa) by absorbing or emitting a phonon. Compared to the electron energy in most solid state materials, the phonon energy is neglectable, such that the electron will (almost) not change its energy when scattering with a phonon. Therefore the phonon can only scatter off the electrons on the Fermi surface. However the greatest possible momentum transfer on the Fermi surface is $2k_F$ (assuming spherical Fermi surface with radius $k_F$). So all scattered phonon must have a momentum $q\leq 2k_F$.